# ¿Se puede crear un chatbot con Whatsapp Business api?

Tags: android-studio, api

Tengo una duda, quiero implementar un chatbot en whatsapp para enviar respuestas automáticas a mis usuarios, pero investigando me encontré con la función de whatsapp Business api pero por lo que leí es como otro whatsapp para empresas con diferentes funciones, mi duda es, se puede crear un ChatBot en whatsapp o debería usar otra forma como DialogFlow?

Answer (score -1):

yo ando realizando lo mismo, encontré algo llamado twilio.com revisa si eso te puede servir de algo, yo hice unas pruebas desde la consola de ellos y funciona pero cuando lo conecto con DialogFlow no responde el mensaje de bienvenida. Dale una revisada a esta documentación https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-whatsapp-chatbot-twilio-dialogflow-php depronto pueda servirte de algo.